# How to locate (not find) a file with no extension in Linux?

Tags: linux

How can I find a file with no extension using `locate`? Can I pipe it through grep if locate can't do it?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you trying to locate a specific file that has no extension or any file that has no extension?

Comment: A file with a certain name but no extension. For instance, if I search for 'test' I want to find all files called test, anywhere, but with no extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is one way to do it:

```
locate -b filename | grep -v '\.'
```

`Locate -b` finds only files with that basename, so not filename/something. The grep bit then finds only files with no extension.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
    locate -b fileName
```